# Xamarin forms collection view show skeleton while data loading

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to show the skeleton of collection view items while data is loading?

Something like linkedin, when loading pages:
[image]

I've seen there exists some packages to make it, but I'm wondering if it's possible directly from Xamarin Forms.

CollectionView or any other layout would help me.

Comment: Syncfusion Shimmer: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/shimmer/overview

Answer (score 2):

Check out Xamarin.Forms.Skeleton: https://github.com/HorusSoftwareUY/Xamarin.Forms.Skeleton